# ICS simultaneously enabled on 2 NICs

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, network-adapter, connection-sharing, ics

I have two network adapters on my laptop, wired an wireless, I frequently switch between, and I want to share Internet connection from them seamlessly.
However, it is cumbersome to enable ICS on each adapter after switching from WiFi to Ethernet and vice-versa, because Windows doesn't allow two simultaneous connections with shared Internet.
I want this: when I connect to Internet via WiFi the system detects it and share Internet from there, when I change connection to Ethernet (and WiFi is disconnected), the system automatically starts to share Ethernet Internet connection. Is there any configuration I can apply to achieve such behavior?
I particularly wish built-in tools (commands, batch scripts, PowerShell scripts), not third-party products.

P.S. My use-case: I wanna share Internet to the internal switch of Hyper-V, for it to be consumed by my VMs.